# please reopen this question

Tags: support

I edited the question and now it should fit into this stack: [Would Axolotl Ratchet protocol be suitable for encrypting email communication?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83083/would-axolotl-ratchet-protocol-be-suitable-for-encrypting-email-communication)

If not, why does it not fit?

Answer (score 4):

It does have 3 reopen votes so it may get reopened. One query I have is around your final sentence:

> Would it be possible to create a mail client plugin (like Enigmail for Thunderbird) that uses axolotl encryption instead of PGP?

This isn't a very useful sentence, because the answer, no matter what encryption you popped in there, would be a Yes. If you took that sentence out the question would make much more sense.

Comment: I changed it to 

"What problems would have to be thought through, when creating a mail client plugin (like Enigmail for Thunderbird) that uses axolotl encryption instead of PGP?"

better?

Comment: much better - reopened now. Thanks

Comment: THX. Should I delete this whole meta question now?

Comment: I tend to think these sort of things are with keeping as examples where a discussion helps improve a post